# Use statically generates messages in React Intl

Tags: reactjs, internationalization, react-intl, babel-plugin-react-intl

I have an object that contains content for a page, I import it and try to use it like you'd use any object variable:

```
import {Variable} from 'data'
const message = defineMessages({
  message: {
    id: 'component.title',
   defaultMessage: Variable.title
  }
})
```

However, I get `React Intl] Messages must be statically evaluate-able for extraction.`. I googled a lot and found no solution to this. I'm using `babel-plugin-react-intl` to generate the locale files, and a contributor said that [Babel can only parse simple statically messages](https://github.com/yahoo/babel-plugin-react-intl/issues/56)

It's hard to believe there's no way to be able to import content from another file and have it translated. There must be a way, I couldn't come up with a solution and help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with the same problem by myself. As far as I know, there's no way to translate a content of a variable in `react-intl`.

If you're interested in alternative solutions, I wrote [jsLingui](https://github.com/lingui/js-lingui) i18n library and recently just added support for [noop translations](https://lingui.gitbooks.io/js/ref/react.html#i18nmark), which is exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you! Yeah I figured after extensive research. I gave up and found an alternative solution of translating the file themselves and using locale folders to store/retrieve them, it's a shame though.

Comment: I have my app already in react-intl, maybe I'll switch it to something else in the future.